# Speech Recognition for Websites

Tags: navigation, speech-recognition, speech

I want to implement speech recognition and navigation in my website. I went through **Annyang** , but Firefox and IE is not supporting. Is there any other solution for this presently using which I can perform speech recognition in all browsers. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer depends on what you are looking for. What kind of navigation are you talking about? Should it be a bunch of pre-defined commands like "go home" or "next page" or do you think about something more natural to human speech?

Comment: @Alexander : Yup. I want it to be pre-defined like when user speaks out "Home" it will go to the home page, "About" then go to about page.  So, user can speak out the link and it will go to the corresponding page.

Comment: Check out this : https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js